# CakePHP - UsersController::admin_login() cannot be accessed directly

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have problem with admin_login method in my REST API based on CakePHP.

frontend is REST api
backend is classical CakePHP admin section (based on admin prefixes)

I try to explain how i tried to create login functionality for admin part of app.

**I added routes in routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_login'));
Router::connect('/admin/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_logout'));
```

**In appController i added auth module**

```
'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_login'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_logout'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.'
        ));
```

**And into beforeFiler callback allowed method**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        // TODO THIS SHOULD BE DEFINED ON EACH CONTROLLER SEPARATED
        $this->Auth->allow('view', 'index','add','admin_login');
```

**In Users controller i added admin_login method**

```
public function admin_login() {
        die('test');
    }
```

And also admin_login.ctp template file.

But if im trying to get URL:

*http://project.loc/admin/*

I get always this error message>

```
Private Method in UsersController
Error: UsersController::admin_login() cannot be accessed directly.
```

**Question is>**

How can i solve it and what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The url arrays you have used for admin prefixed actions are incorrect. For eg. instead of `array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_login')` you need to use `array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true)`.